# Phone Number Hint enable phone number sharing

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services

Phone Number Hint API allows to pick phone number.
According to [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/phone-number-hint/android#how-it-works) user can disable phone number sharing. How to re-enable it?
Where I can find an autofill screen?

[image]

Here is the code I use to call a "Choose phone number" dialog. When user has disable "Phone number sharing" it doesn't work anymore.

```
private val phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        try {
            val phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(requireActivity()).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.data)
            binding?.frgSetupAccountEtPhone?.setText(phoneNumber)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log(e)
        }
    }

private fun requestHint() {
    val request: GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest = GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build()
    Identity.getSignInClient(requireActivity())
        .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            val phoneRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.intentSender).build()
            phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher.launch(phoneRequest)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            log(it)
        }
}
```

Comment: "How to re-enable it? Where I can find an autofill screen?" - make a dialog to ask the user to enable it. Also, provide here some code, because you do not fully understand what you are going to achieve.

Comment: Well, this question is not related to code since I'd like to open Autofill settings as regular user. But if someone knows how to open it programmatically it also can help.
@Yurii

Comment: Clear data of Google Play services, wait some time, and it resets settings. But it is not a user friendly solution. I'd like to find a better one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with

```
startActivityForResult(
    Intent("com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.PHONE_NUMBER_HINT_SETTINGS"),
rcPhoneNumberHint)
```

but, it gives me

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.PHONE_NUMBER_HINT_SETTINGS cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.api.credentials.assistedsignin.ui.PhoneNumberHintSettingsActivity } from ProcessRecord{1343fc7 30196:com.example.app/u0a2478} (pid=30196, uid=12478) not exported from uid 10031
```

I guess they have prevented this Activity to be launched from outside by setting

```xml
android:exported="false"
```

If it is the case then we are out of luck.

If anyone helps to launch "PHONE_NUMBER_HINT_SETTINGS", it will be useful.